# Parse email content from quoted reply using Java

Tags: java, regex, email, email-parsing

I am trying to find out a way to filter out Quoted or replied to text in an email. I used Jsoup and parser-callback. But it wouldn't reliably filter out email Text

This is my approach, but it doesn't work for all cases, like mentioned : [Convert formatted email (HTML) to plain Text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19902403/convert-formatted-email-html-to-plain-text)

Comment: I'm sure you've already worked on something, how about you show us what you got so far, maybe based on that, we make make some progress together. You do understand that we would have to possess magical powers to help you out using the given description?

Comment: @reto : I have already shown my approach here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19902403/convert-formatted-email-html-to-plain-text  I guess I should link it with the question

Answer (score 0):

I use this library and I'm pleased so far: https://github.com/edlio/EmailReplyParser

From their documentation:

```
String reply = EmailReplyParser.parseReply(emailContentString);
```

See doc page for more features